# What is the "correct" way to realize a "flat" result using sequelize N:M associations

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a product database containing some products with 1-n categories. My products are stored in a `products` table, categories are in `categories` and the associations are stored in `productCategoryRel`. Now my wish is, when I get a product using `Product.find()`, to receive a result containing a `categories` property with the data from the `categories` table in it, without any other nested properties.

Currently this is what I get so far:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Testproduct",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Testcategory",
      "productCategoryRel": {
        "category_id": 1,
        "product_id": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So my `product` contains a property `categories` which is great, but `categories` also contains all the data from the `productCategoryRel` table what I want to avoid. I have already googled like hell, studied the docs and whatnot and I'm not really sure if it is even possible what I try to achieve.

This is how I defined my (test)models:

```
let ProductCategoryRel = sequelize.define('productCategoryRel', {});

let Category = sequelize.define('category', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING
});

let Product = sequelize.define('product', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    defaultScope: {
        include: [{
            model: Category
        }]
    }
});
```

And the associations:

```
Product.belongsToMany(Category, {
    through: ProductCategoryRel,
    foreignKey: 'product_id',
});

Category.belongsToMany(Product, {
    through: ProductCategoryRel,
    foreignKey: 'category_id',
});

ProductCategoryRel.hasMany(Product, {foreignKey: 'id'});
ProductCategoryRel.hasMany(Category, {foreignKey: 'id'});
```

And my desired result is just as simple as:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Testproduct",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Testcategory"
    }
  ]
}
```

So is this even possible? How do I need my to change my associations? I already tried some weird hasMany/belongsTo combinations instead but with no success.

I'm using Sequelize 3.12.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (there may be some errors but if you give me feedback we solve problems):

```
Product.findOne({
    where: {
      id: yourProductId
    },
    include: [{
      model : Category,
      order: [['id','desc']],
      through: {attributes: []}
    }],
  })
```

`attributes` property allow you to select what data to show. It may be used also in included models.

more in documentation http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/

Comment: I would like to avoid that if possible since I would have to explicitly exclude every property (even the new ones in case I add some to the model) in every scope which sounds pretty much redundant/overhead.

//edit: and by the way: attributes only seems to work for columns specified in the included model (category in my case) not for relations. I still see `productCategoryRel`

Comment: I have update my code snippet. I add ```through: {attributes: []}``` which should remove from output ```ProductCategoryRel```

Comment: That causes an error:
    `W:\temp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:82
            throw err;
            ^
    TypeError: Cannot set property 'productCategoryRel' of undefined`

pretty weird.

Comment: Without work with this code I can't help more. I leave my answer for now, in order to someone else have a record about what we checked already and may add answer with new proposition.

Comment: Ahh, you were right. I used `attributes[]` instead of `through: { attributes: [] }` - Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help